# How to use OrderBy Linq when object is null and property is integer

Tags: c#, linq

I want to order a collection with a property which is null but if not using a property that is integer.

```
repeaterEmployees.DataSource = employees.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer())
                                        .OrderBy(x => x.Status ?? x.Status.ID);
repeaterEmployees.DataBind();
```

Employees is a class extending the List`Employee. And Employee has a property Status which is from a class Status

I got a message in the OrderBy method "Operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type Status and int"

Comment: Try `.OrderBy(x => x.Status == null ? -1 : x.Status.ID )`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `-1` (or any other value that you know is outside the range of valid ID values) if `Status` is `null` like this:

```
repeaterEmployees.DataSource =
    employees.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer())
    .OrderBy(x => x.Status == null ? -1 : x.Status.ID );
```

Comment: Since we don't know for sure whether Status.ID is negative or positive. How about use int.MinValue to replace -1 in your solution?

Comment: In C#6 this can be even shorter: `x.Status?.ID ?? -1`

Answer (score 0):

If this is coming from a SQL DB you should be fine, null references won't happen if calling into the database. If you just call order by, by default nulls will go to the top.

```
repeaterEmployees.DataSource = employees.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer())
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Status.ID);
repeaterEmployees.DataBind();
```

If your calling from linq to objects you'll have to check for null

```
repeaterEmployees.DataSource = employees.Distinct(new EmployeeComparer())
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Status == null ? -1 : x.Status.ID);
```